# Double quotes and JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object that maps an index and a Key-Value pair object:

`var obj = {0: {key: "{{0:$.data[?(@.first_name=="Janet")].last_name}}", value: "Janet"}}`

Inside the KV pair, there may be a [JSONPath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath) language inside of it. Obviously, JSONPath can contain double quotes, ie `first_name=="Janet"`.

I need to `JSON.stringify()` the `obj`. However, doing so causes the resulting string to have `\` escape chars in them, which breaks the JSONPath parser further down the line.

Result of `stringify()`:

`"{"0":{"key":"{{0:$.data[?(@.first_name==\"Janet\")].last_name}}","value":"Janet"}}"`

Using single `first_name=='Janet'` quotes fixes this problem, however for the sake of usability I don't want my users to reference the JSONPath docs, see that a `""` is valid, just to turn around and tell them that it is invalid in my application.

Assuming that I have to stringify the obj, and that there potentially could be legitimate backslash characters, (ie. `first_name=="foo\baz"`), what is a good way to either

a. Sanitize my `obj` before Stringifying to replace the double quotes with single quotes
b. Fix the result after Stringify to get rid of the `\`
c. Solve this problem in some completely different way that I am not thinking of

Comment: _"causes the resulting string to have \ escape chars in them"_ - That's how it works. Just parse the string back into an actual object.

Comment: if you're trying to "fix" the result of JSON stringify/parse, you're using them (or the result) incorrectly.

Comment: @Andreas that is not an option because the JSONPath parser further down the line requires to have everything in string format. The way it works now:

`obj` -> preProcess() -> `"$.data[?(@.first_name==\"Janet\")].last_name"` -> JSONPathParse() -> Syntax Error

Comment: @Adam  I was hoping to sanitize the object itself with single quotes before sending it to stringify:

Before: `obj = {0: {key: "{{0:$.data[?(@.first_name=="Janet")].last_name}}", value: "Janet"}}`


After: `obj = {0: {key: "{{0:$.data[?(@.first_name=='Janet')].last_name}}", value: "Janet"}}`

Comment: What is the problem with strinigfying it and just letting the quotes exist? If you're consuming a JSON string for something, chances are you'll want to parse it back into an object before you do anything with it - storing in a database excluded, perhaps - (at which point the '\' wont' be a problem). If you're not parsing it back into an object first and trying to do something with the JSON string manually, then you're doing things wrong.

Comment: `$.data[?(@.first_name=="Janet")].last_name` is a [JSONPath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath) query. Say that query returns "Smith". The final result will be `{0: {key: "Smith", value: "Janet"}}`. Essentially, I am trying to take the language instead the `{{ }}`, process it, return its result, then replace the whole query language portion with the result before turning it back into a JSON object. As you know, you can't just put random extra characters in a language without running into a syntax error. Those backslashes cause a syntax error with the JSONPath library

Comment: After you parse back or inside a JSON object, you have still proper quotes also backslash is not any problem - it will be stringtified escaped so doubled \\ ?